# How to use Fabric.js to save a canvas as an image

Tags: javascript, canvas, cross-domain, fabricjs, todataurl

I have a Fabric.js prototype where people can load photos, text, and maps into the canvas. When they're done, I want them to be able to save the canvas as an image. I've tried using the standard:

```
canvasURL = canvas.toDataURL();
var image = new Image();
image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
$('#canvasContainer').replaceWith(image);
```

but it says that the canvas is `tainted` - I think because of the images (the method above works when it's just text). The error is:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

I can use Fabric's built-in method to save as SVG:

```
var canvasSVG = canvas.toSVG();
$('#canvasContainer').replaceWith(canvasSVG);
```

But I'd rather have a PNG/JPG. Any ideas?

Here's the Fabric.js documentation on serialization of the canvas.

http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/#serialization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following must be true:

1. Your cross-domain `<img>` elements must contain a `crossorigin` attribute.
2. The server hosting the images must return an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response with either a wildcard, or your specific domain as the value.
3. The browser must support CORS on `HTMLMediaElement`s, specifically `HTMLImageElement`s.  This is only currently possible in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera 15+

Comment: Note: This _might_ be possible as well in Safari 7 as well.

Answer (score 4):

This works well for me

```
function convertToImagen() {
  canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();  
  window.open(canvas.toDataURL('png')); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, remember that if you're developing on your local computer rather on a server, you will probably see this security error message.

Comment: I couldn't comment because of my reputation.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same issue, solved it by first passing the image url in an ajax call to a php file that would convert the image and return a data url

```
<?php
$content=file_get_contents($_POST['imageurl']);
echo "data:image/png;base64,". base64_encode($content);
?>
```

make sure to set the async:false for the ajax call

you can use the returned data to create your image object and load it on canvas.

Comment: This is potentially dangerous advice.  There is no reason to make this a synchronous call.  Doing so opens up the the possibility of locking up the entire browser if this request takes a noticeable amount of time.  Please consider changing your answer.

Comment: i have been working on an application where in images can be dragged and dropped from folders,browsers, or can be searched for from dropbox accounts or gdrives, i firstly identify the samedomain flag and pass the images for conversion if from a different domain, yes there is a average delay of 3.5 secs depending on the image size considering an average of 2mb with a download speed of 512kbps, but I also proportionately scale own the image to a reasonable size.This has worked well for me so far.please let me know your views

Comment: The bottom line is, never use synchronous Ajax requests in the browser outside of web workers.  Nothing you are doing requires a synchronous call.